# Retrieving changes in Google Docs to calculate contributions of every team member in team drive

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Is there a way to retrieve all changes to a file to calculate the amount of contribution the team member has contributed to a document in team drive? As in get every word that the user has entered into the document

I'm using Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Google drive has the ability to notify you when a file has been changed.  You could then download the file and compare it with the last version of the file you have and then determine how much of the file has been changed since last time.

The only information google drive actually stores itself is the when the file was last changed.  Anything else you are going to have to create yourself.

Comment: Means there is no way for me, for example, to list out the changes without downloading the file?

Comment: No you will have to do the comparison yourself.